# ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `current_order' for OrderItemsController:Class):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm building a store in Rails that has a specific sales model. I need to allow a user to add only 3 items to his order per 30 days. The 30 days counter should start upon adding the first order_item. Once 30 days expires, user would be able to add 3 orders. If 30 days didn't pass and for an example, user adds two order_items he would still be allowed to add one more order_item within 30 days. So as well if user tries to add more then 3 items to show an error message and disregard saving of the order_items to current_user's order.

I'm getting this error in my log right now:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method current_order' for OrderItemsController:Class): app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:15:in <class:OrderItemsController>' app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>''
```

Relevant codes:

order_items_controller.rb

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
 def create
     @item = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)
  session[:order_id] = current_order.id

  if @item.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end 
end

 @order = current_order
      @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
      @order.user_id = current_user.id
      @order.save
      session[:order_id] = @order.id


    end
private

  def order_item_params
  base_params = params.require(:order_item)
                      .permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id)
  base_params.merge(order: current_order)
 end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present
validate :only_3_items_in_30_days

  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end



  def only_3_items_in_30_days
    now = Date.new
    days_since_first = now - order.first_item_added_at

    if order.order_items.count > 2 && days_since_first < 30
      errors.add(:base, 'only 3 items in 30 days are allowed')
    end
    true      # this is to make sure the validation chain is not broken in case the check fails
  end



end
```

And form that is being submitted:

```
<%= form_for OrderItem.new,  html: {class: "add-to-cart"}, remote: true do |f| %>


        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.hidden_field :quantity, value: 1, min: 1 %>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
            <%= f.submit "Add to Cart", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure that you want to order this item for current month?'}, class: "btn btn-default black-background white" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you setting your `current_order`?

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
 def create
     @item = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)
  session[:order_id] = current_order.id

  if @item.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end 
end

# I have no idea of what this method ought to accomplish could you try to explain? but this is the immediate cause of the error. There could be others though.
def method_wrapper
  @order = current_order
  @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
  @order.user_id = current_user.id
  @order.save
  session[:order_id] = @order.id
end
private

  def order_item_params
    base_params = params.require(:order_item)
                      .permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id)
    base_params.merge(order: current_order)
  end
end
```